# How to add superscript & subscript in text in D3

Tags: d3.js

Current Code:

```
.text(function(){return "Area:"+d3.values(expensesTot)[count].area+"mm2";
 });
```

Current Output:

Area: 20mm2

Expected Output:

Area: 20mm<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6738109

You can just do the following :

```
.text(function(){return "Area:"+d3.values(expensesTot)[count].area+"mm²";
 });
```

Working example :

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);

var svgText = svg.append('text').text('This is a test : mm²')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In html I would do `<sup>2</sup>` in D3? In the example given its shown as `formatPower(Math.round(Math.log(d) / Math.LN10))` that wouldn't work for me. I want mm^2 not 10^2.

Comment: @AniMenon Could you elaborate on what that formatPower function does ? Also, my example does give you mm^2 or am I missing something here ?

Comment: In your code you are specifying `mm²` so you get mm^2. My editor doesn't support pasting mm² so how do I do it? [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/wopbbz0h/1/)

Comment: @AniMenon You could use its unicode escape sequence `\u00B2` instead: `"mm\u00B2"`.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer works only for numbers, so for anyone wanting to sub/sup-script their text, here's two methods:

1. Use SVG's `tspan` [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan):

Example (note that it is appended after a `text` element):

```
svg.append('text')
  .attr('x', width / 2)
  .attr('y', height / 2)
  .html('Normal Text')
  .style('font-size', '2rem')
  .append('tspan')
    .text('Subscrit Text')
    .style('font-size', '.1rem')
    .attr('dx', '.1em')
    .attr('dy', '.9em')
```

2. Use SVG's `foreignObject` [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) (note, this method requires styling via css, and (from my experimentation) requires inline styling:

Example with inline css:

```
svg.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", height / 2)
  .append("xhtml:body")
  .html("<p style='font-family:consolas;'=>mm<sup>2</sub></p>")
```

As far as I can tell, the `tspan` method is 'correct' solution, as it allows for styling via SVG attributes, but either will work for using sub/super-scripts with D3.